# Running multiple instances of ChangeFeedProcessor for Azure Cosmos

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to run 2 instances of ChangeFeedProcessor , both pointing towards the **same Collection** and using the **same lease collection** in a Cosmos account. I have specified unique **hostName** in both the instances

My intention is that the Feed load gets distributed amongst the instances according to the logical partitions (as per Microsoft documentation)

When i try to get the 2nd instance up, i get the following exception in console.

Is there any different way to achieve this?

> Exception in thread "pool-23-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.ExceptionClassifier.classifyClientException(ExceptionClassifier.java:56)
>     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.PartitionProcessorImpl.lambda$run$0(PartitionProcessorImpl.java:115)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.block(MonoRunnable.java:66)
>     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.PartitionSupervisorImpl$1.run(PartitionSupervisorImpl.java:89)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Exception in thread
>   "pool-19-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.ExceptionClassifier.classifyClientException(ExceptionClassifier.java:56)
>     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.PartitionProcessorImpl.lambda$run$0(PartitionProcessorImpl.java:115)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.block(MonoRunnable.java:66)
>     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.PartitionSupervisorImpl$1.run(PartitionSupervisorImpl.java:89)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Exception in thread
>   "pool-25-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.ExceptionClassifier.classifyClientException(ExceptionClassifier.java:56)
>     at
>   com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.changefeed.implementation.PartitionProcessorImpl.lambda$run$0(PartitionProcessorImpl.java:115)...etc

I have used the below maven dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

CODE SNIPPET

1. creating a list of ChangeFeedProcessors (for all the containers found in a database)

```java
        //FEED DATABASE
        CosmosDatabase feedDatabase = cosmosClient.getDatabase(cosmosDbName);

        //LEASE DATABASE
        CosmosDatabase leaseDatabase = cosmosClient.getDatabase(cosmosDbName + LEASES);

        //List of Containers in Feed Database
        List<CosmosContainerProperties> containerPropertiesList = null;
        try {
            Flux<FeedResponse<CosmosContainerProperties>> containers = feedDatabase.readAllContainers();
            List<FeedResponse<CosmosContainerProperties>> list = containers.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList());//Abhishek Optimize
            containerPropertiesList = list.get(0).results();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fail to query Containers");
            throw new ServiceException("Fail to query Containers");
        }

containerPropertiesList.parallelStream().forEach(cosmosContainerProperties -> {
                //FEED CONTAINER
                String containerName = cosmosContainerProperties.getString("id");
                CosmosContainer feedContainer = feedDatabase.getContainer(containerName);

                //LEASE CONTAINER
                String leaseContainerName = containerName + "-leases";
                CosmosContainer leaseContainer = leaseDatabase.getContainer(leaseContainerName);

                //Building ChangeFeedProcessor for current Container
                ChangeFeedProcessorOptions changeFeedProcessorOptions = new ChangeFeedProcessorOptions();
                changeFeedProcessorOptions.startTime(OffsetDateTime.now());

                ChangeFeedProcessor changeFeedProcessor = null;
                try {
                    ChangeFeedProcessor.BuilderDefinition builderDefinition = ChangeFeedProcessor.Builder()                           
                            .hostName("Host1")//used Host2 in the other Host
                            .feedContainer(feedContainer)
                            .leaseContainer(leaseContainer)
                            .options(changeFeedProcessorOptions)
                            .handleChanges(docs -> {
                                documentChangeHandler.processChanges(containerName, docs);
                            });
                    changeFeedProcessor = builderDefinition.build();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Fail to initialize ChangeFeedProcessor for " + containerName);
                }
                resultList.add(changeFeedProcessor);

                System.out.println("processed:  " + leaseContainerName);
            });
```

2. The **resultList** is then returned and ChangeFeedProcessors are started in the below method

```java
public void startChangeFeed() {
        if (null != changeFeedProcessors && !changeFeedProcessors.isEmpty()) {
            changeFeedProcessors.parallelStream().forEach(processor->processor.start().block());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("changeFeedProcessors list is empty.. probably changeFeedProcessor has not been setup yet");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you mention which Change Feed Processor version / source code are you using? And a code snippet of how are you initializing each instance?

Comment: I have added the details in the question :)

Comment: According to Maven, 3.0.0 is 6 months old, have you tried with a more recent version? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmos

Comment: hi Matias, 
i tried using the 3.5.0 version, in this one...the changeFeedProcessor itself is failing to start

Getting the error
"Could not initialize class com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity"..

I am sharing the stack trace in the below link>>
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aod8IaE2adONiFTqMTqS_gioti9b?e=YfAcdd

Comment: The stacktrace means that is not able to connect to the Service. It also looks like you are using Direct connectivity. If you are behind a Proxy/VPN/Firewall, please ensure that you have the correct port forwarding/whitelisting. Port ranges are described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#networking

Comment: Thanks, with Gateway mode, seems to work...
Now load is getting distributed amongst the 2 instances i am running, though not uniformly,.....
Instance 1 is getting 90% of the feed, instance 2 only 10%....Is this a configurable parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the issue is related to VPN/Proxy or something blocking the required port ranges.

Direct Mode,needs a certain port range to be open and configured in the VPN/Proxy/Firewall:

[image: Connection Modes]

If configuration is not possible, you can switch to Gateway / HTTP mode.

The Change Feed Processor uses a second Leases collection to store state (mainly explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#components-of-the-change-feed-processor along with .NET samples, but the concepts are the same). The current model creates 1 lease per physical partition (I say current model because this implementation can improve in the future for a better distribution), and each lease, can be owned by 1 instance only. So if you have 2 leases, and 2 instances, 1 lease will be owned by each.

Each instance will process the changes in the partition/s based on the lease/s it owns.

A load distribution of 90/10 means that the changes happening in your collection seem to be skewed to happen mainly in one partition (hot partition) and not equally distributed.